# is the norm of the absolute value of a functional equal to the norm of the functional?

Tags: functional-analysis

Lets say that I have a functional on a normed vector space $V, \| . \|_V$, $\psi : V \to \mathbb{R}$.

Then is $\|\psi \| = \| |\psi| \|$?

I'm thinking that since $\psi$ maps to $\mathbb{R}$ by using the defintion of absolute value

$$
|\psi| =
\begin{cases}
 \psi, \ \psi > 0 \\
-\psi, \ \psi < 0
\end{cases}
$$

Then $\| \psi \| = |-1| \|\psi \| = \| - \psi \| = \| |\psi| \|$ if $\psi < 0$

Comment: It's norm a norm on $V$ more than that we dont know. @LeBtz

Comment: If by $\|\psi\|$ you mean the operator norm of $\psi$, then yes $\|\psi\| = \||\psi|\|$. You see that if you plug in the definition. However, $|\psi|$ is not even a functional anymore.

Comment: Yes the operator norm, and yes it is not a functional anymore, my bad. @LeBtz